# duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy' in:

Tags: ios, xcode

1. **duplicate symbol '*OBJC_CLASS*$_EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy' in:**
   . Xcode/DerivedData/projectName-dgbysnyqlfnahyeugjvjiklqgpqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXPermissions/libEXPermissions.a(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)
   . Xcode/DerivedData/projectNamdgbysnyqlfnahyeugjvjiklqgpqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)

2.**duplicate symbol '*OBJC_METACLASS*$_EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy' in**:
. Xcode/DerivedData/projectNamedgbysnyqlfnahyeugjvjiklqgpqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/EXPermissions/libEXPermissions.a(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)
. Xcode/DerivedData/projectNamedgbysnyqlfnahyeugjvjiklqgpqz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/UMReactNativeAdapter/UMReactNativeAdapter.framework/UMReactNativeAdapter(EXReactNativeUserNotificationCenterProxy.o)

ld: 7 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Please add some explanation here and format your post properly

Answer (score 1):

The first line indicates that it is a problem with the XXXX.o file. A look at the error message shows that it is a link error.
Translate, first of all, you can know that the error message was wrong when linking XXXX.o. Then the ld: 5 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 below means that there are 5 duplicate symbols under the x86-64 architecture. Duplication is a keyword. Analysis There are two situations that may cause this error to occur:

Some files have been imported repeatedly in the project. Generally, this may be imported repeatedly when importing the third party library.
Solution: You only need to find the repeatedly imported file in the file directory and delete it, or delete the entire tripartite library, re-import it, or import it with cocopods.
#Import"XXXX.h" is needed in some parts of the project and #import"XXXX.m" is misused.
Solution: Check the project carefully and find the error and correct it.
two.

If the first line is XXXX.a or XXXX.framwork, then it is probably the Link Binary With Libraries problem. You can find out if there

You can also use the lipo command to disassemble the .a library and delete the duplicate files in it.

```objectivec
lipo XXXX.framework/XXXX -thin armv7 -output XXXX_armv7
```

for more,look here: https://blog.csdn.net/yepiaouang/article/details/79353377